# Is it safe to concatenate SQL statement if user input is not used directly?

Tags: postgresql

Everything I have read says concatenation in SQL is a security flaw. Yet I wonder if I have a structure in Python like this:

```
columnNames = [ column_zero, column_one ]

if userInput == 0:

    columnIndex = 0

elif userInput == 1:

    columnIndex = 1
```

And then in SQL (psycopg2) I concatenate the query:

```
'UPDATE tableName 
SET ' + columnNames[ columnIndex  ] + ' = %s
WHERE id = %s', ( directUserInput, 1 )
```

Are there any security risks here?

Here is the often quoted red ink warning in bold and caps from [psycopg docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters):

> Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or
> string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query
> string. Not even at gunpoint.

For double safety I implemented the new `psycopg2.sql` module they got:

```
sql.SQL( 'UPDATE tableName 
SET {} = %s
WHERE id = %s' ).format( sql.Identifier( columnNames[ columnIndex ] ) ), [ directUserInput, 1 ]
```

Yet I wonder, what's wrong with properly sanitized concatenated string in query? If the user puts in `';DROP DATABASE;'` into either script, nothing should happen. Is there some bit-banging going on in python interpreter that makes concatenation dangerous?

Comment: Depends on the "...".

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I expanded ... but I'm assuming everything except for the concatenation part is safe

Comment: With double safety you've only halved the risk.  Keep going!  BTW, I don't want to know what could go wrong, since there is a method where it can't.  It needs a little effort, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's dangerous. Use pg8000 and prepared statements.